# Using multiple command queues in OpenCL and mapped buffers. Do I get a conflict?

Tags: c, image-processing, opencl, gpu, gpgpu

I use `OpenCL` on the Snapdragon 800 platform. Since `GPU` memory is shared, I can map a memory buffer into main memory, and can directly write on it. This avoids memory copy between `GPU` and RAM.

I wanted to know, if I could write into the mapped memory with my CPU and execute other `OpenCL` programs in other command queues at the same time.

If you want a little bit background, continue reading:

I am using a webcam to capture images, and the webcam library has a function like getImage(). This function blocks execution as long as there is a new frame. For 30 fps, thats 33ms in worst case. During this time, my buffer is mapped, because OpenCL gives me a pointer and I have to forward this pointer to the Webcam libary. When the call is done, I can unmap the `OpenCL` buffer.
I got advanced image processing algorithms implemented on the `GPU`, and NOT ALL OF THEM USE THE MAPPED BUFFER.

Answer (score 0):

While a buffer if mapped, it is not valid to execute any commands that use that buffer. If you want to execute commands that use different buffers, that is fine.

In OpenCL 2.0, the new shared-virtual memory feature allows you to concurrently access a buffer from the host and device.